# Is there a way to turn off safari's overscroll?

Tags: macos, safari, scrolling

Alright, so safari's showing-linen-when-overscrolled thing is old and really ugly. Is there a way to disable it with an `options` command?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is any way to disable the "bounce" when you scroll past the end of a page in Safari.

The reason it exists is so the user knows the computer got the scroll command. Especially with Lion's reversed scrolling, people are likely to scroll the wrong way. This way, the less-savvy user knows that it was they that did it wrong: the computer didn't crash or hang. It's also a nice way to signal the end of a page.

Comment: Sad thing is that it only looks good with white backgrounds =/